# Delphi bitwise proc convert to PHP

Tags: php, delphi, bit-manipulation

I have a fairly simple function in Delphi which takes a string and produces a hashed integer based on that string:

```
function TfrmMain.HashElf(const Buf;  BufSize : LongInt) : LongInt;
 var
 Bytes : TByteArray absolute Buf;
 I, X  : LongInt;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := 0 to BufSize - 1 do begin
    Result := (Result shl 4) + Bytes[I]; 
    X := Result and $F0000000;
    if (X <> 0) then  Result := Result xor (X shr 24);
    Result := Result and (not X);
  end;
end;
```

I'm converting it to PHP but the results are not the same.  This is what i've got in PHP:

```
function HashElf($Buf, $BufSize){
  $Bytes = str_split($Buf);

  for ($i= 0; $i<$BufSize;$i++){
    $Result = ($Result << 4) + Ord($Bytes[$i]);

    $X = $Result & (0xF0000000);
    if ($X<>0){$Result = $Result ^ ($X>>24);}

    $Result = ($Result & (~ $X));
  }
  return $Result;
}
```

if you pass in the string teststring to the Delphi function you get 195831015 however PHP returns 72559895.  I noticed the difference only becomes apparent after 7 characters.  If the test string is just test the results are identical.

PHP seems to have some difficulty with shifting a negative integer to the right  for example the folowing line:

```
 if ($X<>0){$Result = $Result ^ ($X>>24);}
```

changed to shift left $X<<24 produces the same values as Delphi for the variable X, but the results are still different.

Am i missing something really obvious here?

EDIT:
The output of the two functions are:

Delphi

```
  Char: t   Result: 116        X: 0
  Char: e   Result: 1957       X: 0
  Char: s   Result: 31427      X: 0
  Char: t   Result: 502948     X: 0
  Char: s   Result: 8047283    X: 0
  Char: t   Result: 128756644  X: 0
  Char: r   Result: 181058242  X: 1879048192
  Char: i   Result: 212577321  X: -1610612736
  Char: n   Result: 180011582  X: -1073741824
  Char: g   Result: 195831015  X: -1610612736
```

PHP

```
  Char: t   $Result: 116         $X: 0
  Char: e   $Result: 1957        $X: 0
  Char: s   $Result: 31427       $X: 0
  Char: t   $Result: 502948     $X: 0
  Char: s   $Result: 8047283    $X: 0
  Char: t   $Result: 128756644  $X: 0
  Char: r   $Result: 181058242  $X: 1879048192
  Char: i   $Result: 212577417  $X: -1610612736
  Char: n   $Result: 180013310  $X: -1073741824
  Char: g   $Result: 195858503  $X: -1610612736
```

So its not until character "i" that php starts to get off track with the calculations

EDIT2:

Added PHP function to do a logical right shift instead of arithmetic shift:

```
function lshiftright($var,$amt)
{
  $mask = 0x40000000;
  if($var < 0)
  {
    $var &= 0x7FFFFFFF;
    $mask = $mask >> ($amt-1);
    return ($var >> $amt) | $mask;
  }else{
    return ($var >> $amt);
  }
}
```

This now works!  Also thanks Ignacio for the mask idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure Delphi is right and PHP is wrong?

Delphi's shl and shr apparently can behave unpredictably with **signed** integers. See: http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/del-bits.htm#SAR. Dr. Stockton seems to imply there are two types of shift operations: arithmetic shift (keeping the sign) and logical shifts.

The docs ( http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/expressions_xml.html ) aren't very clear on the effect of shl/shr on signed integers. They do however mention that shr/shl by one is only comparable to divions/multiplication by 2 for **unsigned** integers.

I couldn't find what Dr. Stockton (from the first link) calls the logical shift operations, but it would seem logical :-) to try changing the delphi implementation to use an unsigned 8-byte type (DWORD comes to mind) and see what effect that has.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - checking the PHP manual again revels that bit shifting is arithmetic only.  I had it working in Delphi with an additional bit mask, but then i figured it would be better to force PHP to do what i want - see edit for additional code

Answer (score 1):

Mask the bits you want.

```
if ($X<>0){$Result = ($Result ^ ($X>>24)) & 0xFF;}
```

Comment: thanks, though the number of bits i need are 0x7FFFFFFF.  This means that the results are still inconsistent between Delphi and PHP.  Also, the two routines will be run in conjuction with one another, so they need to produce the same results every time.

Comment: If you're right-shifting 24 then no, you only have 8 bits left.